# React Native SDK IOS - Error

Tags: error, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, sdk, react-native

I need help installing the SDK in the IOS application. An error is appearing in the process of performing the "Build"
We follow this documentation: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

On android it was fine, but on IOS it shows the following error:
Use of undeclared identifier 'MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder'
Use of undeclared identifier 'mcsdkBuilder'

PS. App in react native

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the import statement at the very top.

```
// Add this import at the top (before #if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED)
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.h>
```

Reference:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk#2-configure-the-sdk-in-your-appdelegatem-class